# cocos2d/box2d trouble

Tags: ios, sdk, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have just started working with cocos2d and box2d for iOS SDK, and have a few problems. I got the templates working, and got the test app (the one where you click the screen and a box with a random letter appears) to compile.

My first problem is that I can't figure out how to get a blank template. Is there a quick way to do this when I begin a new app?

My second problem is that I can't figure out how to just simply change the color of an object. I can define something like this:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2CircleShape circle;
circle.m_radius = .5f;//These are mid points for our 1m box

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &circle;
fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.1f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.3f;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

But is there a simple way to make something a certain color?

Final question: does this sample app have the accelerometer-gravity enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making a certain body a specific color, assign 'userData' to the body. userData is your sprite with specific color you wanted

And reply to your final answer is YES.

Answer (score 2):

For making blank template do the following

1. Remove these lines from -(id) init

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"blocks.png" capacity:150];
[self addChild:batch z:0 tag:kTagBatchNode];
[self addNewSpriteWithCoords:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];

CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Tap screen" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
[self addChild:label z:0];
[label setColor:ccc3(0,0,255)];
label.position = ccp( screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height-50);
```

1. Remove the function

```
-(void) addNewSpriteWithCoords:(CGPoint)p
```

1. Remove the following line from - (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

```
[self addNewSpriteWithCoords: location];
```

Try it out. :)